# Single quotes in string are replaced by escaped double quotes after Nodejs update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, json

Just updated my NextJS app's dependencies of Node (from 16 to 18.x) and React (from 17 to 18) and this strange error started happening.

We have this piece of code that takes an object and creates a `<script>` tag out of it. Stringifying the object and using custom `replacer` for the functions.

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  return typeof value === 'function' ? value.toString() : value; 
}

const content = "window._testconfig_ = " + JSON.stringify(config, replacer);

// where config is an object like 
const config = {
  someOption: true,
  someFunction: () => { 
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('EventName'))
  }
}
```

After updating the dependencies I'm getting this string:

`window._testconfig_ = {"someOption":true,"someFunction":"() => { \n    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(\"EventName\"))\n  }"}`

where before the single quotes were preserved for `'EventName'`. This content added to a script tag breaks the bundle (throws Unexpected character for the extra `\`).

There's a cleanup function for newline characters `\n` and I can also replace the escaped double qoutes there, but need to investigate why this happens. Is it caused by the new version of Node, or some React dependency?

Comment: I've just tried your replacer with `JSON.stringify` on the `config` you've shown in Node v11 through Node v20. In all cases, the result contained `'EventName'`. So this wouldn't immediately seem to be down to Node.js version. That said: Having double quotes in functions isn't exactly rare, code that can't handle double quotes in functions should probably be fixed regardless of why you're suddenly seeing this change.

Comment: For instance: Since converting the function's code to a string which is then JSON-ified may have other negative effects given the way you're using the result, you might have the replacer return a unique placeholder for each function, then post-process the resulting string to insert the function source code. ...

Comment: ... rough sketch: ```function toScript(obj) { const functions = new Map(); let functionId = 0; function replacer(key, value) { if (typeof value === 'function') { const id = String(++functionId); functions.set(id, value.toString()); return `__function_id_${id}__`; } return value; } const script = JSON.stringify(config, replacer).replace(/"__function_id_(\d+)__"/g, (_, id) => functions.get(id)); return script; }```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to the Nodejs version change, where the JSON.stringify works differently.
Here, as you are stringifying the JSON, it includes all back lashes and single quotes.
So, you should try to escape all the backlashes and keep all the single quotes as well.
For that, you should modify the return statement of the first check in replacer function using regular expression as below:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  return typeof value === 'function' ? value.toString().replace(/\\|'/g, '\\$&') : value; 
}
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Thanks, Hardik, that helps too. The replacer and stringifying are part of a library and is really important to know which version of Node breaks, if that information is available.